# Str.split() en Python

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy intentando separar en varias columnas los datos de la celda de una columna en concreto haciendo la separación por espacios en blanco.
Me gustaría que los nombres de las columnas en que se subdividan tengan todas el mismo nombre. El problema es que el número de datos en la celda a dividir es variable.

```
personas = pd.DataFrame({'Nombres': ['Jorge Sanz', 'Almudena Cid', 'Ernesto Alterio']})
personajes = personas.join(personas.pop('Nombres').str.split(expand=True))


    0   1
0   Jorge   Sanz
1   Almudena    Cid
2   Ernesto Alterio
```

El problema es que quiero crear tantas columnas como apellidos aparezcan y que todas tengan el nombre `Apellidos` pero hay veces que vienen 3 apellidos o 4... y quiero que, para cada vez que corra el proceso, independientemente del número de apellidos que haya cree tantas columnas llamadas `Apellidos` como apellidos contengan los datos.

Gracias

Comment: Que intentaste hasta ahora para lograr tu objetivo?

Comment: Buen día, si un `dataframe` tiene más de una columna con el mismo nombre, automáticamente se transforman a `'X.0'...'X.N'` es decir, son renombradas para poder ser identificadas y esto únicamente funciona cuando importas el `dataframe` de algún archivo o sitio web. Si lo intentas hacer manualmente únicamente sobre escribirías la misma columna N veces.

Comment: Eso había pensado, entonces no es posible no?

Comment: Podrías nombrarlos "Apellido_1".."Apellido_N" pero es necesario que agregues tu código para mostrar que eres parte de la cultura del sitio al intentar resolver tu problema. Sin el código que has intentado utilizar es muy probable que la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente

Comment: Ahora, si tienes un `string` ¿Cómo identificarías si la palabra es nombre o apellido? Es posible que alguien tenga 2 nombres y 2 apellidos

Comment: En realidad no habrá nombres compuestos, y si los hubiera que los dividiese en tantas columnas me valdría también. Lo que pasa es que aparte de que no se me ocurría nada, tenía la sospecha de que no se podrían repetir nombres de columnas y el que se puedan repetir es totalmente necesario

Comment: ¿Para qué sería necesario? Toda esta información debería ir en la pregunta. Si es necesario para filtrar o seleccionar columnas todavía podrías hacerlo aunque tuvieran un sufijo.

Comment: Todo esto es para crear y subir un csv a partir de esto y es necesario que tengan el mismo nombre. En cualquier caso, ¿habría alguna manera de colocarle un título aunque lleven sufijos a cada una de estas columnas que se crean de número variable?

Comment: Podrías hacer dos niveles de columnas, el nivel 0 que sea apellidos y un segundo nivel que sean los números de la columna, o como comenté anteriormente podrías agregarle un número como sufijo.

Comment: Por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, no como imagen y el código que has intentado utilizar

Answer (score 0):

Para crear tantas columnas como palabras tenga el nombre con más palabras de tu dataframe usaremos el método `split` con el argumento `expand=True`.

```py
nombres_apellidos = personas['Nombres'].str.split(expand=True)
```

Contamos cuántos apellidos necesitamos como máximo.
Restamos uno porque una de las columnas será para el nombre.

```py
num_apellidos = nombres_apellidos.shape[1] - 1
```

Nombramos las columnas de `nombres_apellidos`:

```py
nombres_apellidos.columns = ['Nombre'] + ['Apellido'] * num_apellidos
```

Tenemos tantas columnas como palabras tenga el nombre con más palabras y el resto de las columnas se llaman todas `Apellido`.
Si quisiéramos además conservar la columna original, basta con concatenar las columnas:

```
personas = concat([personas, nombres_apellidos], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes separar los nombres de los apellidos estableciendo un "*formato*" de separación cuando los apellidos sean mayor a 1 y que los nombres sean menor o igual a 2, esto quiere decir que cada valor debería de tener un límite de 2 nombres y 2 o más apellidos.

```
personas = pd.DataFrame({'Nombres': ['nombre1 nombre2 apellido1 apellido2', 'nombre1 apellido1', 'nombre1 nombre2 apellido1']})
                               Nombres
0  nombre1 nombre2 apellido1 apellido2
1                    nombre1 apellido1
2            nombre1 nombre2 apellido1
```

definir columna `'apellidos'` separando el valor de cada fila en `'Nombres'` según su longitud usando el método `split`

```
personas['apellidos'] = personas['Nombres'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[2:]) if len(x.split(' ')) >= 3 else ' '.join(x.split(' ')[1:]))
                               Nombres            apellidos
0  nombre1 nombre2 apellido1 apellido2  apellido1 apellido2
1                    nombre1 apellido1            apellido1
2            nombre1 nombre2 apellido1            apellido1
```

repetir el proceso usando la indexación de manera opuesta `[2:], [1:]`, `[:2], [:1]`

```
personas['Nombres'] = personas['Nombres'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:2]) if len(x.split(' ')) >= 3 else ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:1]))
           Nombres            apellidos
0  nombre1 nombre2  apellido1 apellido2
1          nombre1            apellido1
2  nombre1 nombre2            apellido1
```